# Display Text and Image in same Position

Tags: javascript, jquery

we are allowing user to upload an image  once user click on car....

[image]

Once user Upload the image , we are displaying the user uploaded image on top of the car & displaying text "**Edit**" outside the container....

[image]

**Requirement** :

But I want to display that text in a same position as of the image....

[image]

if car position is `left : 1px`
I want the text position also should be `left : 1px`

Codepen : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/vMLzdJ

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/kidsdial1/s1vukmxh/1/

```js
var target;
var imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png";

// Json file - it includes car image and its positions

let jsonData = {
    "layers": [{
        "x": 10,
        "height": 412,
        "layers": [
            {
                "x": 20,
                "layers": [{
                        "x": 30,
                        "src": "iEA642D.jpg",
                        "y": 31,
                        "name": "L2b-1"
                    }
                    
                ],
                "y": 21,
                "name": "user_image_1"
            }
        ],
        "y": 11,
        "width": 412,
        "name": "L1"
    }]
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    // ignore below code - it  will upload image onclick car

    $('.container').click(function(e) {

        var res = e.target;
        target = res.id;
        console.log(target);
        if (e.target.getContext) {
            // click only inside Non Transparent part
            var pixel = e.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
            if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $('#fileup').click();
                }, 20);
            }
        }
    });

    // Below code will fetch car image from json file

    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y,
                    name: layer.name
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y,
                        name
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y),
                            name: (name)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

    function json(data)

    {
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;

        let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);

        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1[0].width;
        height = layer1[0].height;
        let counter = 0;
        let table = [];

        for (let {
                src,
                x,
                y,
                name
            } of arr) {
            $(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');
            if (name.indexOf('mask_') !== -1) {
                var imageUrl1 = imageUrl;
            } else {
                var imageUrl1 = '';
            }
            var mask = $(".container").mask({
                imageUrl: imageUrl1,
                maskImageUrl: 'https://i.imgur.com/' + src,
                onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {

    // car positions : 
    
                    img.css({
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "left": x + "px",
                        "top": y + "px"
                    });

                },
                id: counter
            });
            table.push(mask);
            fileup.onchange = function() {

                let mask2 = table[target];
                const newImageLoadedId = mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";

                //  Edit text

    $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
    "<br/><span style =\"left:  layer.x + 'px;'\" class=\"edit\" >Edit </span>" +
    "</span>").insertAfter("#fileup");

                // Edit code end here....
               
            };
            counter++;
        }

    }
    json(jsonData);
}); // end of document ready

// ignore below code

(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);


        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;

        container.mousePosition = function(event) {
            return {
                x: event.pageX || event.offsetX,
                y: event.pageY || event.offsetY
            };
        }

        container.selected = function(ev) {
            var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
            var item = $(".masked-img canvas").filter(function() {
                var offset = $(this).offset()
                var x = pos.x - offset.left;
                var y = pos.y - offset.top;
                var d = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                return d[0] > 0
            });

            JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
                var id = item.length > 0 ? $(item).attr("id") : "";
                if (el.id == id)
                    el.item.enable();
                else el.item.disable();
            });
        };

        container.enable = function() {
            draggable = true;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 2
            });
        }

        container.disable = function() {
            draggable = false;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 1
            });
        }

        container.updateStyle = function() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function() {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });
                    resolve();
                };
            });
        };

        function renderInnerImage() {
            img = new Image();
            img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
            img.src = settings.imageUrl;
            img.onload = function() {
                settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
                settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;
                context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
                initImage = false;
            };
        }

        // change the draggable image

        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
            console.log("load");
            //if (img)
            // img.remove();
            // reset the code.
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            initImage = true;
            container.updateStyle().then(renderInnerImage);
            // sirpepole  Add this
            return settings.id;
        };


        // change the masked Image
        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            // div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event)
            div.find("canvas").on('dragstart', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.onDragStart(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.selected(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);
            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
        };
        container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.temp {}

.container {
 background: gold;
  position: relative;
 
}

.container img {
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   bottom:250px;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   margin:auto;
   z-index:999;
}

.masked-img {
 overflow: hidden; 
 position: relative;
}


.txtContainer{ position:absolute;  text-align:center; color:#FFF}

.txtContainer:hover {
     background: red;
     padding: 1px;
 border-style: dotted;
}

.pip {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
.remove {
  display: block;
  background: #444;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.remove:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

.edit {
  display: block;
  background: #444;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  position:relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
.edit:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  position:relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

.white_content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  padding: 16px;
  border: 16px solid orange;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1002;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none" >

<div class="container">

</div>
```

Comment: Can’t really tell what the actual question is here - how to move those elements to a specific position, or how to determine what that position would need to be in the first place?

Comment: looking for [this](https://jsfiddle.net/monim67/opub4256/)?

Comment: @MunimMunna Thanks a lot , Its working fine for single image, please give me some time, i will try your code for multiple images.....

Comment: @MunimMunna When i tried with 2 images in  [codepen](https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/mgPNWO) ,  it displayed `Edit` button only one time.... can you please check once.....

Comment: @MunimMunna what i want is `edit` button should display dynamiclally for any numbers of images  here i have 8 images : https://jsfiddle.net/r54wqfmv/

Comment: In codepen use `$("<span class=\"pip\">" + ... ).insertAfter("#"+target)`, in jsFiddle use `$(".masked-img #" + newImageLoadedId)`.

Comment: @MunimMunna sorry for delay, i followed your suggestion for codepen , it worked for 2 images & also for 8 images, but there is some small problem in that is `edit` button will disappear if we click on other images as here : [video link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y3GjtN9bjO9jpItWCXWZYBSNHIYl5amw/view) , here is codepen : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/rbMKWX

Comment: @MunimMunna same issue for 9 images also : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/jRMKyQ

Comment: @MunimMunna ii think its because `edit` text is overlapping with other images ,so i tried to put the `edit` text inside middle of image , so i tried `$("<span class=\"pip\">" +
          "<span style =\"left:  layer.x + (layer.width/2) +  'px;' top:  layer.y + (layer.height/2) + 'px;'  \" class=\"edit\" >Edit </span>" +
          "</span>").insertAfter("#"+target);` , but its not calculating layer.width and layer.height..... please help me....

Comment: @MunimMunna Thanks for your time , other solution helped me.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**CSS changes - ** Update `.pip` **CSS** with the below **CSS**.

```
.pip {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

**Script Changes - Just change insert div to `.masked-img`. Calculate and apply `left`, `top` spaces.**

All the mentioned changes updated in a below code snippet. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```
$("<span class=\"pip\">" +
    "<span class=\"edit\" >Edit </span>" +
    "</span>").insertAfter(".masked-img").css({"left": x + "px", "top": y - $('.pip').height() + "px"});
```

```js
var target;
var imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png";

// Json file - it includes car image and its positions

let jsonData = {
    "layers": [{
        "x": 10,
        "height": 412,
        "layers": [
            {
                "x": 20,
                "layers": [{
                        "x": 30,
                        "src": "iEA642D.jpg",
                        "y": 31,
                        "name": "L2b-1"
                    }
                    
                ],
                "y": 21,
                "name": "user_image_1"
            }
        ],
        "y": 11,
        "width": 412,
        "name": "L1"
    }]
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    // ignore below code - it  will upload image onclick car

    $('.container').click(function(e) {

        var res = e.target;
        target = res.id;
        console.log(target);
        if (e.target.getContext) {
            // click only inside Non Transparent part
            var pixel = e.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
            if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $('#fileup').click();
                }, 20);
            }
        }
    });

    // Below code will fetch car image from json file

    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y,
                    name: layer.name
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y,
                        name
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y),
                            name: (name)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

    function json(data)

    {
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;
        var leftValue = 0;

        let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);

        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1[0].width;
        height = layer1[0].height;
        let counter = 0;
        let table = [];

        for (let {
                src,
                x,
                y,
                name
            } of arr) {
            $(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');
            if (name.indexOf('mask_') !== -1) {
                var imageUrl1 = imageUrl;
            } else {
                var imageUrl1 = '';
            }
            var mask = $(".container").mask({
                imageUrl: imageUrl1,
                maskImageUrl: 'https://i.imgur.com/' + src,
                onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {

    // car positions : 
    
                    img.css({
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "left": x + "px",
                        "top": y + "px"
                    });

                },
                id: counter
            });
            table.push(mask);
            fileup.onchange = function() {

                let mask2 = table[target];
                const newImageLoadedId = mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";

                //  Edit text

    $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
    "<span class=\"edit\" >Edit </span>" +
    "</span>").insertAfter(".masked-img").css({"left": x + "px", "top": y - $('.pip').height() + "px"});

                // Edit code end here....
               
            };
            counter++;
        }

    }
    json(jsonData);
}); // end of document ready

// ignore below code

(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);


        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;

        container.mousePosition = function(event) {
            return {
                x: event.pageX || event.offsetX,
                y: event.pageY || event.offsetY
            };
        }

        container.selected = function(ev) {
            var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
            var item = $(".masked-img canvas").filter(function() {
                var offset = $(this).offset()
                var x = pos.x - offset.left;
                var y = pos.y - offset.top;
                var d = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                return d[0] > 0
            });

            JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
                var id = item.length > 0 ? $(item).attr("id") : "";
                if (el.id == id)
                    el.item.enable();
                else el.item.disable();
            });
        };

        container.enable = function() {
            draggable = true;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 2
            });
        }

        container.disable = function() {
            draggable = false;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 1
            });
        }

        container.updateStyle = function() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function() {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });
                    resolve();
                };
            });
        };

        function renderInnerImage() {
            img = new Image();
            img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
            img.src = settings.imageUrl;
            img.onload = function() {
                settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
                settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;
                context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
                initImage = false;
            };
        }

        // change the draggable image

        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
            console.log("load");
            //if (img)
            // img.remove();
            // reset the code.
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            initImage = true;
            container.updateStyle().then(renderInnerImage);
            // sirpepole  Add this
            return settings.id;
        };


        // change the masked Image
        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            // div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event)
            div.find("canvas").on('dragstart', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.onDragStart(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.selected(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);
            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
        };
        container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.temp {}

.container {
 background: gold;
  position: relative;
}

.container img {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:250px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:auto;
  z-index:999;
}

.masked-img {
 overflow: hidden; 
 position: relative;
}

.txtContainer{ 
  position:absolute; 
  text-align:center; 
  color:#FFF
}

.txtContainer:hover {
  background: red;
  padding: 1px;
 border-style: dotted;
}

.pip {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.remove {
  display: block;
  background: #444;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.remove:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

.edit {
  display: block;
  background: #444;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  position:relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
.edit:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  position:relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

.white_content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  padding: 16px;
  border: 16px solid orange;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1002;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none" >
<div class="container"></div>
```

**Another option If you have multiple images.**

```js
var target;
var imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png";

// Json file - it includes car image and its positions

let jsonData = {
  "path" : " newyear collage\/",
  "info" : {
    "author" : "",
    "keywords" : "",
    "file" : "newyear collage",
    "date" : "sRGB",
    "title" : "",
    "description" : "Normal",
    "generator" : "Export Kit v1.2.8"
  },
  "name" : "newyear collage",
  "layers" : [
    {
      "x" : 0,
      "height" : 612,
      "layers" : [
        {
          "x" : 0,
          "color" : "0xFFFFFF",
          "height" : 612,
          "y" : 0,
          "width" : 612,
          "shapeType" : "rectangle",
          "type" : "shape",
          "name" : "bg_rectangle"
        },
        {
          "x" : 160,
          "height" : 296,
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,
              "height" : 296,
              "src" : "iEA642D.jpg",
              "y" : 0,
              "width" : 429,
              "type" : "image",
              "name" : "mask_image_1"
            },
            {
              "radius" : "26 \/ 27",
              "color" : "0xACACAC",
              "x" : 188,
              "y" : 122,
              "height" : 53,
              "width" : 53,
              "shapeType" : "ellipse",
              "type" : "shape",
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse1"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 291,
          "width" : 429,
          "type" : "group",
          "name" : "user_image_1"
        },
        {
          "x" : 25,
          "height" : 324,
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,
              "height" : 324,
              "src" : "iEA642D.jpg",
              "y" : 0,
              "width" : 471,
              "type" : "image",
              "name" : "mask_image_2"
            },
            {
              "radius" : "26 \/ 27",
              "color" : "0xACACAC",
              "x" : 209,
              "y" : 136,
              "height" : 53,
              "width" : 53,
              "shapeType" : "ellipse",
              "type" : "shape",
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse_2"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 22,
          "width" : 471,
          "type" : "group",
          "name" : "user_image_2"
        }
      ],
      "y" : 0,
      "width" : 612,
      "type" : "group",
      "name" : "newyearcollage08"
    }
  ]
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    // ignore below code - it  will upload image onclick car

    $('.container').click(function(e) {

        var res = e.target;
        target = res.id;
        console.log(target);
        if (e.target.getContext) {
            // click only inside Non Transparent part
            var pixel = e.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
            if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $('#fileup').click();
                }, 20);
            }
        }
    });

    // Below code will fetch car image from json file

    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y,
                    name: layer.name
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y,
                        name
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y),
                            name: (name)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

    function json(data)

    {
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;

        let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);

        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1[0].width;
        height = layer1[0].height;
        let counter = 0;
        let table = [];

        for (let {
                src,
                x,
                y,
                name
            } of arr) {
            $(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');
            var imagePosition = arr;
            if (name.indexOf('mask_') !== -1) {
                var imageUrl1 = imageUrl;
            } else {
                var imageUrl1 = '';
            }
            var mask = $(".container").mask({
                imageUrl: imageUrl1,
                maskImageUrl: 'https://i.imgur.com/' + src,
                onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {

    // car positions : 
    
                    img.css({
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "left": x + "px",
                        "top": y + "px"
                    });

                },
                id: counter
            });
            table.push(mask);
            fileup.onchange = function() {

                let mask2 = table[target];
                const newImageLoadedId = mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";

                //  Edit text 

              if($(".masked-img" + newImageLoadedId).length === 1) {
    $("<span class=\"pip\">" + 
    "<span class=\"edit\" >Edit </span>" +
    "</span>").insertAfter(".masked-img" + newImageLoadedId).css({"left": imagePosition[newImageLoadedId].x + "px", "top": imagePosition[newImageLoadedId].y - $('.pip').height() + "px"});
                // Edit code end here....
              }         
            };
            counter++;
        }

    }
    json(jsonData);
}); // end of document ready

// ignore below code

(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);


        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;

        container.mousePosition = function(event) {
            return {
                x: event.pageX || event.offsetX,
                y: event.pageY || event.offsetY
            };
        }

        container.selected = function(ev) {
            var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
            var item = $(".masked-img canvas").filter(function() {
                var offset = $(this).offset()
                var x = pos.x - offset.left;
                var y = pos.y - offset.top;
                var d = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                return d[0] > 0
            });

            JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
                var id = item.length > 0 ? $(item).attr("id") : "";
                if (el.id == id)
                    el.item.enable();
                else el.item.disable();
            });
        };

        container.enable = function() {
            draggable = true;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 2
            });
            if(!div.hasClass('masked-img0') && !div.hasClass('masked-img1')) {
               div.addClass('masked-img1');
            }
        }

        container.disable = function() {
            draggable = false;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 1
            });
            if(!div.hasClass('masked-img0') && !div.hasClass('masked-img1')) {
               div.addClass('masked-img0');
            }
        }

        container.updateStyle = function() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function() {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });
                    resolve();
                };
            });
        };

        function renderInnerImage() {
            img = new Image();
            img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
            img.src = settings.imageUrl;
            img.onload = function() {
                settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
                settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;
                context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
                initImage = false;
            };
        }

        // change the draggable image

        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
            console.log("load");
            //if (img)
            // img.remove();
            // reset the code.
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            initImage = true;
            container.updateStyle().then(renderInnerImage);
            // sirpepole  Add this
            return settings.id;
        };


        // change the masked Image
        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            // div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event)
            div.find("canvas").on('dragstart', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.onDragStart(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.selected(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);
            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
        };
        container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.temp {}

.container {
 background: gold;
  position: relative;
}

.container img {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:250px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:auto;
  z-index:999;
}

.masked-img {
 overflow: hidden; 
 position: relative;
}

.txtContainer{ 
  position:absolute; 
  text-align:center; 
  color:#FFF
}

.txtContainer:hover {
  background: red;
  padding: 1px;
 border-style: dotted;
}

.pip {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.remove {
  display: block;
  background: #444;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.remove:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

.edit {
  display: block;
  background: #444;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  position:relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
.edit:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  position:relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

.white_content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  padding: 16px;
  border: 16px solid orange;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1002;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none" >
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, When i tried for 2 images, it displaying `Edit` only one time,  can you please check & help me : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/yrOWWJ

Comment: Thank you @vickeycolors for the response. **2 images work** first, you have to update the structure. Currently, when I add the first image it automatically creates 2 **edit** buttons for both images. Edit task will automatically resolve when you fixed the structure issue. Thanks

Comment: sorry for that , are you telling about this :  https://prnt.sc/n7wdgg ?

Comment: for image1 , its taking `left:25px; top:22px;` but for image2 also , its taking same dimensions, instead for image2 - it should take `x : 160, y : 291` as present in [json](http://139.59.24.243/ecom1/site/test/2images.json) file....

Comment: Yes, I know that can you give some time. I need to review your code. Thanks

Comment: I just update your code with few script changes. Now edit will be visible for both images according to there positions. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191326/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-hassan-siddiqui).

Answer (score 1):

So, I believe that you are looking for something similar to this:

In the jQuery you can add this instead of your edit code:

```
$(".masked-img").append("<span class=\"pip\">" +
"<br/><span style =\"left:  layer.x + 'px;'\" class=\"edit\" >Edit </span>" +
"</span>");
```

This code will append your span to the masked img div (the one that contains the image).

You tried to set position relative in the text inside the span, and that did not work, this is because you need the direct parent to be position absolute (and the direct parent is the `pip` span. Instead add this:

```
.pip {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
  position: relative;
  top: -200px; // The height of the canvas
}
```

And remove `position: relative;` from `.edit`.

And that should just work.
[image: Visualization of the solution]

As in your previous question, I am assuming you want to touch as little as possible your code base but it would be helpful for you to learn CSS and JavaScript.
If you had the correct HTML structure it would be easier for you to do this kinds of things without any need to do some tricks like I posted (`-200px`? that just feels bad). For example if your HTML looked like this:

```
<section id="input-container">
  <div class="image-editor" >
    <div class="edit"><button>edit</button></div>
    <div class="mask-img" >...</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

But for this you will need major changes in your code and that is out of scope for this question.

Comment: That is because you asign top to the Edit Span, that as I said in my answer, is within the pip span, if you want to add top: layer.y, you must do it in the span id="pip"

Comment: sorry , i tried your code here : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/bJpXvv , but  `Edit` button is displaying only because we gave top :-200px, but i need to get that using layer.x & layer.y

Answer (score 0):

Replace 
 insertAfter("#fileup");
With 
insertBefore(".masked-img canvas");

```js
var target;
var imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png";

// Json file - it includes car image and its positions

let jsonData = {
    "layers": [{
        "x": 10,
        "height": 412,
        "layers": [
            {
                "x": 20,
                "layers": [{
                        "x": 30,
                        "src": "iEA642D.jpg",
                        "y": 31,
                        "name": "L2b-1"
                    }
                    
                ],
                "y": 21,
                "name": "user_image_1"
            }
        ],
        "y": 11,
        "width": 412,
        "name": "L1"
    }]
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    // ignore below code - it  will upload image onclick car

    $('.container').click(function(e) {

        var res = e.target;
        target = res.id;
        console.log(target);
        if (e.target.getContext) {
            // click only inside Non Transparent part
            var pixel = e.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
            if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $('#fileup').click();
                }, 20);
            }
        }
    });

    // Below code will fetch car image from json file

    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y,
                    name: layer.name
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y,
                        name
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y),
                            name: (name)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

    function json(data)

    {
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;

        let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);

        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1[0].width;
        height = layer1[0].height;
        let counter = 0;
        let table = [];

        for (let {
                src,
                x,
                y,
                name
            } of arr) {
            $(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');
            if (name.indexOf('mask_') !== -1) {
                var imageUrl1 = imageUrl;
            } else {
                var imageUrl1 = '';
            }
            var mask = $(".container").mask({
                imageUrl: imageUrl1,
                maskImageUrl: 'https://i.imgur.com/' + src,
                onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {

    // car positions : 
    
                    img.css({
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "left": x + "px",
                        "top": y + "px"
                    });

                },
                id: counter
            });
            table.push(mask);
            fileup.onchange = function() {

                let mask2 = table[target];
                const newImageLoadedId = mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";

                //  Edit text

    $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
    "<br/><span style =\"left:  layer.x + 'px;'\" class=\"edit\" >Edit </span>" +
    "</span>").insertBefore(".masked-img canvas");

                // Edit code end here....
               
            };
            counter++;
        }

    }
    json(jsonData);
}); // end of document ready

// ignore below code

(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);


        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;

        container.mousePosition = function(event) {
            return {
                x: event.pageX || event.offsetX,
                y: event.pageY || event.offsetY
            };
        }

        container.selected = function(ev) {
            var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
            var item = $(".masked-img canvas").filter(function() {
                var offset = $(this).offset()
                var x = pos.x - offset.left;
                var y = pos.y - offset.top;
                var d = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                return d[0] > 0
            });

            JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
                var id = item.length > 0 ? $(item).attr("id") : "";
                if (el.id == id)
                    el.item.enable();
                else el.item.disable();
            });
        };

        container.enable = function() {
            draggable = true;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 2
            });
        }

        container.disable = function() {
            draggable = false;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 1
            });
        }

        container.updateStyle = function() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function() {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });
                    resolve();
                };
            });
        };

        function renderInnerImage() {
            img = new Image();
            img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
            img.src = settings.imageUrl;
            img.onload = function() {
                settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
                settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;
                context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
                initImage = false;
            };
        }

        // change the draggable image

        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
            console.log("load");
            //if (img)
            // img.remove();
            // reset the code.
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            initImage = true;
            container.updateStyle().then(renderInnerImage);
            // sirpepole  Add this
            return settings.id;
        };


        // change the masked Image
        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            // div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event)
            div.find("canvas").on('dragstart', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.onDragStart(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.selected(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);
            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
        };
        container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.temp {}

.container {
 background: gold;
  position: relative;
 
}

.container img {
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   bottom:250px;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   margin:auto;
   z-index:999;
}

.masked-img {
 overflow: hidden; 
 position: relative;
}


.txtContainer{ position:absolute;  text-align:center; color:#FFF}

.txtContainer:hover {
     background: red;
     padding: 1px;
 border-style: dotted;
}

.pip {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
.remove {
  display: block;
  background: #444;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.remove:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

.edit {
  display: block;
  background: #444;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  position:relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
.edit:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  position:relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

.white_content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  padding: 16px;
  border: 16px solid orange;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1002;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none" >

<div class="container">

</div>
```